Connection between ultraproduct and Robinson's method of diagrams
In Simon Kochen's introduction to "Ultraproducts in the theory of models" it is claimed that

In $10, we show that there is a
connection between ultraproducts and A. Robinson's method of diagrams

However, going to section 10 I don't see an explicit mention of Robinson's diagrams. Not being familiar with this part of model theory, it would be helpful expert's understanding on this relation.
